# vue.js imported module is undefined inside promise callback

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am using a simple store like implementation in my vue.js application. I have defined the store like this:

```
     // File: my_store.js
     var invoiceDetailStore = {

        state: {
           selectedInvoiceId: null,
           selectedInvoiceDetails: {}
        },

        setSelectedInvoiceId(selectedId, comp) {
           console.log('selectedInvoiceId updated by ' + comp + ' with value ' + selectedId);
           this.state.selectedInvoiceId = selectedId;
        },

        setSelectedInvoiceDetails: (invoiceDetails, comp) => {
           console.log('selectedInvoiceDetails updated by ' + comp + ' with value ' + invoiceDetails);
           this.selectedInvoiceDetails = invoiceDetails;
        },

        addSelectedInvoiceDetail: (invoiceDetail, comp) => {
           console.log('InvoiceDetail added by ' + comp + ' with value ' + invoiceDetail);
           this.selectedInvoiceDetails.push(invoiceDetail);
        }
     };

     export { invoiceDetailStore };
```

In my component i have imported the store. When a watched property changes in the component, i make an axios call and then trying to call a method on the store inside the success callback of axios, like this:

```
 // mycomponent.vue
 import { invoiceDetailStore } from '../Shared_State/invoice_detail_store.js';

 export default {
 data() {
     return {
        shared: invoiceDetailStore.state,
        selectedInvoice: {},
     };
  },

  mounted: function() {
     console.log(invoiceDetailStore);   // This prints the store properties and functions....
  },
  watch: {
     selectedInvoiceId: function(newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log(invoiceDetailStore);    // THIS prints undefined
        if(newValue !== oldValue) {
           axios('my/get/url')
           .then(response => {
              this.selectedInvoice = response.data.invoice_summary; // it sets the local data property called selectedInvoice 
              invoiceDetailStore.setSelectedInvoiceDetails(response.data.invoice_details);   // .......... invoiceDetailStore is undefined
           })
           .catch(errorResponse => {
             // error actions here
           });
        }
     }
  },
}
```

As you can see from the comments, i get `Cannot read property 'setSelectedInvoiceDetails' of undefined`. However, the `invoiceDetailStore` is not undefined inside the mounted hook.

Can anyone please guide to the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: There are various errors in the store implementation but they won't cause this error. The arrow functions shouldn't be arrow functions, that'll give you the wrong `this` value. It also seems to forget to use `state` about half-way down. Are you sure that you're interpreting the logging correctly? How do you know exactly which log line can from where? e.g. Try logging `console.log('mounted', invoiceDetailStore);` so you can be sure which line came from the `mounted` hook.

Comment: There was another comment on my question a while ago that said the arrow functions in the store were the issue, as you have indicated. I changed all arrow functions in the `store` to regular functions and that fixed the issue. What i do not understand is why the arrow functions caused the whole `invoiceDetailStore` object to be undefined inside the axios `.then` callback, whereas inside the mounted hookd the `invoiceDetailStore` was OK!!! Any idea? Also could you please post your comment as answer, so that i can accept it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The earlier comment was also from me. I reworded it because I felt the original comment gave the false impression that the arrow functions were the cause of the error message you reported. I still don't believe there's a direct link between the two, even if it appears to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, here is my comment as an answer. I stress that while this does fix important bugs in your code I see no reason why it would address the specific error message posted in the question.

You've got a couple of functions in your 'store' like this:

```js
setSelectedInvoiceDetails: (invoiceDetails, comp) => {
    console.log('selectedInvoiceDetails updated by ' + comp + ' with value ' + invoiceDetails);
    this.selectedInvoiceDetails = invoiceDetails;
},
```

As this is using an arrow function it will be using the wrong `this` value. Further, it isn't accessing `selectedInvoiceDetails` via `state`. I believe it should be changed to:

```js
setSelectedInvoiceDetails (invoiceDetails, comp) {
    console.log('selectedInvoiceDetails updated by ' + comp + ' with value ' + invoiceDetails);
    this.state.selectedInvoiceDetails = invoiceDetails;
},
```

I would suggest investigating further to establish why this seems to fix the problem. It could, for example, be that you were working with a cached version of the code and the change above merely flushed out that cache.

Answer (score 2):

You should not import store into a single component.

> Vuex provides a mechanism to "inject" the store into all child
>   components from the root component with the store option (enabled by
>   Vue.use(Vuex))

So you only import the store when you create your root vue instance and pass it to the constructor. Here is an example from the documentation.

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  // provide the store using the "store" option.
  // this will inject the store instance to all child components.
  store,
  components: { Counter },
  template: `
    <div class="app">
       <counter></counter>
    </div>
  `
});

Vue.use(Vuex)
```

> By providing the store option to the root instance, the store will be injected into all child components of the root and will be available on them as this.$store.

Also be aware that there is a difference between `function() {}` and `() => {}`. The first one will create its own scope, while the later will take its parents scope. Many problems in Vue related to undefined variables on scope or undefined `this` keyword are related to this and can be solved by using `() => {}`.

Comment: While your answer would generally correct the issue, i am not using vuex, rather a simpler form of store like implementation. Thank you.

Comment: oh I just assumed you are using vuex. sorry.

Comment: The last paragraph saved hours. its very important to know the scope.! thanks